# couldn't insert data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i couldn't insert data to database. i don't know where the problem but when i `var_dump($this->mberita->get_berita());` the result is `array(0){}`. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this.

model

```
function get_berita()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id_berita','asc');
    $data = $this->db->get('berita_ukm');
    return $data->result();
}

//untuk menambah berita
function insert_berita($data)
{
    $data = array(
            'id_berita' => $this->input->post('id_berita'),
            'tanggal' => $this->input->post('tanggal'),
            'judul_berita' => $this->input->post('judul_berita'),
            'content' => $this->input->post('content')          
        );

    $this->db->insert('berita_ukm', $data);
}

function validate_berita()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_berita', 'Id Berita', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal', 'Tanggal', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul_berita', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

controller

```
function tambah_berita()
{
    if ($this->mberita->validate_berita() == TRUE) {
        $this->mberita->insert_berita();
        redirect('admin/berita/tambah_berita');
    } 

    $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('admin/berita/tambah_berita', '', true);
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/admin/wrapper_ukm',$this->data);
}
```

Please help me what to do. Thank you.

Comment: does the table `berita_ukm` actually contain any rows?

Comment: If you get any errors, please post it here

Comment: did you load the database lib? next - echo a result field straight from your get_berita() method to see what the issue is. its probably something simple. and doing form validation in the model is fine - keep those controllers thin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
#in controller page# 
// notes : you should make validation in controller page 

    if ($this->input->post('send')){ //request submit 

    // make form validation 

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_berita', 'Id Berita', 'required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal', 'Tanggal', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul_berita', 'Judul Berita', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Content', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
           // request data then put in array
           $data = array(
                'id_berita' => $this->input->post('id_berita'),
                'tanggal' => $this->input->post('tanggal'),
                'judul_berita' => $this->input->post('judul_berita'),
                'content' => $this->input->post('content')          
            );
      $this->mberita->insert_berita($data);
        }
    }
```

//model page

```
        function insert_berita($data)
    {
       $this->db->insert('berita_ukm', $data);
    }
```

Comment: thank you but i try this but its still not working. data couldn't insert to database. so what to do?

Comment: Are shows mistakes? Are you sure you want to include a library database db ?

Comment: no. yes,of course. when i var_dump its still array(0){}

Comment: in model page 
try to edit this line -- >function insert_berita($data)
to -->function insert_berita($data = '')
or delet $data from function($data)